# ArchBang - Missing wireless interface, or how to remap fn+F1-F1

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wifi, archbang

Hello I am using ArchBang on old laptop Dell D410 ([Dell D410 Technical Specification](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/latit/en/spec_latit_d410_en.pdf)). I have troubles with wifi. My assumption (please read bellow explanation why I deducted this) is that I cannot even enable the wifi adapter with keyboard shortcuts (fn+F2). Before current installation of ArchBang release, the box was running on Windows XP with legacy version (unfortunately I do not remember the exact version) of ArchBang in dual boot. On Windows XP the wifi was running correctly. On legacy  version of ArchBang there was the same problem which I have with actual version of ArchBang. When I tried to enable wifi (using fn+F2) on legacy ArchBang the message: “problem with mapping of keyboard shortcut (or something similar)” was written to dmesg (or maybe `/var/log/messages` sorry I do not remember exactly). The box was then reinstalled to recent version of ArchBang hoping it will solve the problem. Now when I press fn+F2 I do not get any message not in dmesg nor in `/var/log/messages`. However I’ve tried to issue `xev` and see what happens: and the result is that all shortcuts (brightness, sound control etc.) are working fine (also in real, and in the `xev` the codes are returned as well), except those which controls wifi (fn+F2). So my assumption is that I have problem not directly with wifi but with enabling the adapter. Wireless is enabled in BIOS, the wireless LED is not flashing. Can I issue some command from command line to enable wifi interface instead of using fn+F2 shortcut? Bellow are output of commands that I have issued:

```
[root@arch ~]$ uname -a
Linux arch 3.11.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 14 08:49:01 CEST 2013 i686 GNU/Linux

[root@arch ~]# ifconfig -a
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.170  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::212:3fff:fe21:70fe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:12:3f:21:70:fe  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1369  bytes 1326271 (1.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1250  bytes 160246 (156.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16 

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@arch ~]# dmesg | grep -i wireless
[    9.064627] ipw2200: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200/2915 Network Driver, 1.2.2kmprq
[    9.065083] ipw2200: Detected Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection

[root@arch ~]# lshw -C network
  *-network              
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:12:3f:21:70:fe
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.132 duplex=full firmware=5751-v3.29a ip=192.168.1.170 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:dfdf0000-dfdfffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:02:03.0
       version: 05
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=24 mingnt=3
       resources: memory:dfcff000-dfcfffff

[root@arch ~]# lsmod | grep -i intel
snd_intel8x0           23721  1
snd_ac97_codec         89336  1 snd_intel8x0
snd_pcm                63876  2 snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0
snd_page_alloc          5974  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
snd                    44566  6 snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0,snd_timer,snd_pcm
intel_agp               8688  1 i915
intel_gtt              10172  3 i915,intel_agp
agpgart                22047  3 drm,intel_agp,intel_gtt
[root@arch ~]# lsmod | grep -i ipw2200
ipw2200               128525  0
libipw                 22318  1 ipw2200
lib80211                3037  2 libipw,ipw2200
cfg80211              336964  2 libipw,ipw2200

[root@arch ~]# modinfo ipw2200
filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.5-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/ipw2200.ko.gz
firmware:       ipw2200-bss.fw
firmware:       ipw2200-sniffer.fw
firmware:       ipw2200-ibss.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2006 Intel Corporation
version:        1.2.2kmprq
description:    Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200/2915 Network Driver
srcversion:     DC12C86CD79304BB5E0D6DB
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004224sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004223sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004221sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004220sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002762bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002761bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002754bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002753bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002752bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002751bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002742bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv0000103Csd00002741bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002741bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002732bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002731bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002722bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002721bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002712bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002711bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002702bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001043sv00008086sd00002701bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211,libipw,lib80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.11.5-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 686
parm:           disable:manually disable the radio (default 0 [radio on]) (int)
parm:           associate:auto associate when scanning (default off) (int)
parm:           auto_create:auto create adhoc network (default on) (int)
parm:           led:enable led control on some systems (default 1 on) (int)
parm:           debug:debug output mask (int)
parm:           channel:channel to limit associate to (default 0 [ANY]) (int)
parm:           rtap_iface:create the rtap interface (1 - create, default 0) (int)
parm:           qos_enable:enable all QoS functionalitis (int)
parm:           qos_burst_enable:enable QoS burst mode (int)
parm:           qos_no_ack_mask:mask Tx_Queue to no ack (int)
parm:           burst_duration_CCK:set CCK burst value (int)
parm:           burst_duration_OFDM:set OFDM burst value (int)
parm:           mode:network mode (0=BSS,1=IBSS,2=Monitor) (int)
parm:           bt_coexist:enable bluetooth coexistence (default off) (int)
parm:           hwcrypto:enable hardware crypto (default off) (int)
parm:           cmdlog:allocate a ring buffer for logging firmware commands (int)
parm:           roaming:enable roaming support (default on) (int)
parm:           antenna:select antenna 1=Main, 3=Aux, default 0 [both], 2=slow_diversity (choose the one with lower background noise) (int)


xev:
###

fn+F2 (Wireless)
##########
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x7f, subw 0x0, time 1416790, (14,261), root:(578,476),
    state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x7f, subw 0x0, time 1416790, (14,261), root:(578,476),
    state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False


fn+F3 (Some battery event - No one knows because batery is old and not used)
################################################
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x7f, subw 0x0, time 1481398, (-28,389), root:(536,604),
    state 0x0, keycode 244 (keysym 0x1008ff93, XF86Battery), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x7f, subw 0x0, time 1481398, (-28,389), root:(536,604),
    state 0x0, keycode 244 (keysym 0x1008ff93, XF86Battery), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

fn+F3 (Enables/Disable NumLock)
#####################
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x7f, subw 0x0, time 1558307, (-50,327), root:(514,542),
    state 0x0, keycode 77 (keysym 0xff7f, Num_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x7f, subw 0x0, time 1558370, (-50,327), root:(514,542),
    state 0x10, keycode 77 (keysym 0xff7f, Num_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

PS: I am writing here because this post was deleted from ArchLinux forums with statement that ArchLinux forums do not support ArchBang, so I registered do ArchBang forums but so far I am unable to post questions (there was troubles with spam or something like this, so now the registration takes longer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command does the trick:
`pacman -S ipw2200-fw`

The wifi is now working but there is still issues with LED. It is not flashing nor lighting